# Ubuntu cron.daily returns a path error when a shell glob is used - what's wrong with my path?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

In Ubuntu 16.04, this is the code I have in `/etc/cron.daily/cron_daily`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in "/var/www/html/*/"; do
if pushd "$dir"; then
wp plugin update --all --allow-root
wp core update --allow-root
wp language core update --allow-root
wp theme update --all --allow-root
rse
popd
fi
done
```

I setted this up yesterday and today I got this error into my email:

> /etc/cron.daily/cron_daily:
>
> /etc/cron.daily/cron_daily: line 3: pushd:
>   /var/www/html/*/: No such file or directory

Why is this happening? I assume the quote marks prevent the shell globbing but if so, what should replace them?

Comment: Something that confused me: In my shell `Bash`, indeed, as the answerers said, one cannot expand a shell glob / shell wildcard inside quote marks but one can do it with above-the-shell utilities like `find`.

Comment: The `find` program does its own expansion in the latter case you mention. While `find` may imitate the shell's behavior, what is happening behind the scenes is different since `find` is not the shell and calling what `find` is doing a "shell glob" may be more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending the path with * does not work in double quotes.

You could try it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do
  if pushd "$dir"; then
    wp plugin update --all --allow-root
    wp core update --allow-root
    wp language core update --allow-root
    wp theme update --all --allow-root
    rse
   popd
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Path expansion does not work in the double quotes.

Simple test:

```
$ ls -ld /lib*
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Jul 14  2017 /lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun 21  2017 /lib64

$ ls -ld "/lib*"
ls: cannot access '/lib*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: So I should just remove the double quotes around `/var/www/html/*/`? Nothing should replace these?